# passing svg google areachart to c# codebehind

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, svg, google-visualization

am trying to pass a google areachart (svg) to a c# codebehind, have tried to add the svg html to a hidden field but so far when I add the html to the hidden field value the javascript that generates the chart is being added rather than the svg tag and the corresponding data.

I have been using the javascript below to pass the the contents of the div containing the chart:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var chartsvg = document.getElementById('ctl00_Body_chartcontent');
            var serializer = new XMLSerializer();
            var str = serializer.serializeToString(chartsvg);
            $('input[name^="ctl00$Body$svgData"]').val(str);
            var test = $('input[name="ctl00$Body$svgData"]').val();
            alert(test);
        });
</script>
```

Once I have passed it to the codebehind I plan on converting the svg to a png.

The alert is for testing what has been added to the hidden field.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I could do this?

Thanks in advanced for any advice given.

Comment: I suspect that your problem is that you are running this on document ready instead of waiting for the chart to draw.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/jwwt3jo8/

Comment: thanks that worked great, modified your jsfiddle so that the function runs when the print preview button is clicked